# I want means, add UIToolbar on UIImagePickerController of SourceType PhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

I want means, add `UIToolbar` on `UIImagePickerController` of SourceType PhotoLibrary.

I tried use:

```
[UIViewController presentViewController:UIImagePickerController completion:^{}];
```

One time was like successfully.
But, PhotoLibrary's UINavigation Back button use then `UIToolbar` is hidden.

Please, how means or References, Documents, others.

I tried use `presentViewController: completion: block`.

```
- (void)showPhotoLibrary {

    if ( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] ) {
        return;
    }

    UIImagePickerController* ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [ipc setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [ipc setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:^{
        [ipc setToolbarHidden:NO];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self resolved. thank you.

```
- (void)showPhotoLibrary {

    if ( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] ) {
        return;
    }

    UIImagePickerController* ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [ipc setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [ipc setDelegate:self];

    UIToolbar* tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    float tbh = 44.0f;
    float tbw = [[ipc view] frame].size.width;
    float tby = [[ipc view] frame].size.height - tbh;
    [tb setFrame:CGRectMake(0, tby, tbw, tbh)];

    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:^{
        [[ipc view] addSubview:tb];
    }];
}
```